# If store is buffered, load method won't load anything

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to detect when something has loaded in store, however I just discovered that if the store is buffered, when load is called everything works fine except data isn't directly load.

I can easily disable buffered to test it (everything works fine again), so I don't understand how can I fire a load call like the grid does.

I need to load my records, are there any way? Yes I can disable "buffered" anyway, but if the grid can load my stores, I should be able to load too. Which is the correct method to use?

I did some tests with loadPage and loadData but they don't work. Do anyone know the method I should use to load data on a store when using a buffered store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a design decision and prefetch method will be used.

I suggest at the moment to avoid buffered stores however. It seems that they aren't widely tested and will give you problems with combobox (no paging system actually if store is buffered, also display problems) and other similar things.